# Parsing xml using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am trying to parse a dom element.

Element element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://X/feed2</id>
  <title>Sample Feed</title>
  <entry>
    <id>http://X/feed2/104</id>
    <title>New Title</title>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I am trying to fetch the following entry:

```
<entry>
  <id>http://top.cs.vt.edu/libx2/vsony7@vt.edu/feed2/104</id>
  <title>New Title</title>
</entry>
```

I am parsing the xml by using the xpath:

"/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:id=\"http://X/feed2/104\"]"

But, I get an exception when I try to parse Dom Element. Can someone suggest a simple approach to achieve this in Java?

Please see my full code:

```
public static parseXml() {
        String externalEntryIdUrl = "http://theta.cs.vt.edu/~rupen/thirtylibapps/137";
        String externalFeedUrl = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(externalEntryIdUrl, "/");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(externalFeedUrl);
            InputStream externalXml = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(externalXml);
            Element externalFeed = doc.getDocumentElement();
            String atomNameSpace = "xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"";
            String entryIdPath = String.format("//%s:entry[%s:id=%s]", atomNameSpace, atomNameSpace, externalEntryIdUrl);
            Element externalEntry = (Element) XPathSupport.evalNode(entryIdPath, externalFeed);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Throw exception
        }
    }

static synchronized Node evalNode(String xpathExpr, Node node) {
    NodeList result = evalNodeSet(xpathExpr, node);
    if (result.getLength() > 1)
        throw new Error ("More than one node for:" + xpathExpr);
    else if (result.getLength() == 1)
        return result.item(0);
    else
        return null;
}

static synchronized NodeList evalNodeSet(String xpathExpr, Node node) {
        try {
                static XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
                xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);

                static NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContext() {
                    private Map<String, String> prefix2URI = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    {
                        prefix2URI.put("libx", "http://libx.org/xml/libx2");
                        prefix2URI.put("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
                    }
                };

            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpr);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            return (NodeList)result;
        } catch (XPathExpressionException xpee) {
            throw new Error ("An xpath expression exception: " + xpee);
        }
    }
```

SEVERE: >>java.lang.Error: An xpath expression exception: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException

Comment: *"I get an exception"*  Is that a `TooManyKittensException`?  Desex the tom cat.   Something else?  Perhaps you might share it (i.e. copy/paste) with us.

Comment: Have you associated (registered the namespace) in your Java code the prefix `atom` to the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`? You have either to do this (recommended) or use something like: `/*/*[local-name() = 'entry'][*[local-name() = 'id'] = 'http://X/feed2/104]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I didn't set the namespace awareness while fetching the xml from a URL.

So,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Doing so fixes my issue. Without doing this, setting the namespace context for XPathFactory instance while parsing the xml as shown in my example doesn't work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAX parser.
Here is a example for SAX parsing http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage a `NamespaceContext`and do something like the following:

```
package forum9059851;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
            xp.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
            XPathExpression xpe = xp.compile("ns:feed/ns:entry");
            FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream("src/forum9059851/input.xml");
            InputSource xmlInput = new InputSource(xmlStream);
            Element result = (Element) xpe.evaluate(xmlInput, XPathConstants.NODE);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Throw exception
        }
    }

    private static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if("ns".equals(prefix)) {
                return "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and want to parse feed data I would recommend going with the already available [Rome](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home) library.